# sqlite3 diffrent WHERE statements on multiple COUNT(*)

Tags: sqlite

i'am making a medal table like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKoNw.png).

I got a table with. Countrycode, medalColor and medalId.

my goal is to get the same output as is showed on the picuture, but i cant get mulitple WHERE statements to work.

It works with one statemen, but then i dont know how to get them together. [single statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkGVC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the column `medalColor` contains values like `'Gold'`, `'Silver'` and `'Bronze'`, you can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
select c.CountryName Land, 
       coalesce(t.Gold, 0) Goud,
       coalesce(t.Silver, 0) Zilver,
       coalesce(t.Bronze, 0) Brons
from country c  
left join (
  select CountryCode,
         sum(medalColor = 'Gold') Gold,
         sum(medalColor = 'Silver') Silver,
         sum(medalColor = 'Bronze') Bronze
  from medaille
  group by CountryCode
) t on t.CountryCode = c.CountryCode
order by Goud desc, Zilver desc, Brons desc
```